# How to check if command line arguments are lower case/ alphabetic and the sort?

Tags: c

I am really new to C programming (have previously done python and this is quite a difficult transition). I have been given a task to check the command line arguments and those which are not lower case alphabetic or numeric should be printed out with a given statement.

I have tried using a for loop and tried checking `islower` for `argv[i]` but that just crashes my program. The compiler gives this warning:

> passing argument 1 of 'islower' makes integer from pointer without a cast

Can someone please give a general idea without actually typing out the code? Please do no type the code as I really want to do this myself (and also might get into trouble for plagiarism).

Comment: What does your current attempt look like? You should post your code since `argv[i]` could mean anything.

Comment: The code you mentioned you wrote? If you post it as part of your question (don't forget to format it), we can probably tell you where things are wrong, and how to correct them. Don't forget to include *all* the error messages *verbatim*, and point out which parts of them you don't seem to understand.

Comment: @WhozCraig: On the contrary, the failure mode is completely obvious from the question, in which case I for one don't mind the odd question that isn't just a code dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`islower()` checks the case of a single character, whereas `argv` is a `char **` variable, meaning that `argv[i]` is a string (a `char *`), not a character. Thus, to check whether a particular argument is lower-case, you need to iterate over the characters in it to check each one.

Which is also the meaning of the warning message you mention. Since the argument to `islower()` is an `int` (a single character), and you pass it a pointer (that is, `argv[i]`, which is a `char *`), the compiler implicitly casts that pointer to the `int` that `islower()` requires, which is seldom intended behavior.

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful. Is it by any chance possible to iterate over each character using getchar? I know we can use it when the input is using scanf but can it be used for command line inputs?

Comment: @Khalid: No, `getchar` is for I/O, but there's really no need. Strings are just `char` arrays, so you can iterate over them just like you do with the arguments themselves. `argv[0][0]` is the first character of the first string in `argv`.

Comment: Okay. Thank you so very much for such prompt replies.